# XQuery with dynamic Index

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic, xquery

i am trying to use XQuery in SQL Server, but I need that the index be dynamic:

This is my query:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(yourXML AS XML).value('(/integracao/item/NumPedido)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') NumPedido
FROM 
    #xml
```

What I have tried:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(yourXML AS XML).value('(/integracao/item/NumPedido)[sql:variable("@index")]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') NumPedido
FROM 
    #xml
```

But it returns this error:

> XQuery [#xml.yourXML.value()]: 'value()' requires a singleton (or
>   empty sequence), found operand of type 'xdt:untypedAtomic *'

Can somebody please help me?

Comment: To quote one of the the close: off-topic options: *Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this post by [Mikael Eriksson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/569436/mikael-eriksson) [in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18743212/how-to-pass-a-variable-into-xpath-of-xquery-in-an-sql-statement)

```
declare @Index INT = 2
declare @XML XML = '
<Root>
    <Element>Hello</Element>
    <Element>World</Element>
</Root>
'
SELECT @xml.value ('(/Root/Element)[sql:variable("@Index")][1]', 'varchar(100)')
```

the `[1]` is simply a way to tell SQL Server that you need a single node.

Comment: It Works!! Thank you so much...  =D